# Arduino Uno Analog pot values are not smooth

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread

I have tired Arduino smoothing example but mine analog value are not staying constant even when I don't rotate the potentiometer. I am mapping the values from 0 -> 1024 to 0-> 100. I have tried exponential filter also but the result is same.

Values change 2 to 3 point mostly. Any idea how can I make the readings much more smooth.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE. You might find this post on our Meta site helpful: [How to ask a good question for Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/how-to-ask-a-good-question-for-arduino-stack-exchange).

Comment: please include a diagram of the circuit ... include the pot value

Comment: Dividing a normal (270 degree linear) potentiometer into 100 sectors is pushing to the limit. You can add hysteresis so it does not wander between adjacent values. Better is to use a rotary encoder.

Comment: Without seeing your filtering code we cannot say why they didn't smooth the values enough. Please share your code. It also depends on the noise your circuit is receiving (and its frequencies)

Comment: @6v6gt can you guide me or share the link how Can I add the hysteresis?

Comment: @chrisl I will add the code to today

Comment: @Arslan Hysteresis. https://forum.arduino.cc/t/hysteresis/506190  It includes an example with a potentiometer but, from experience, 100 sectors is the outer limit of what can be achieved.

Comment: Help yourself by helping us help you. Post a Schematic, not a frizzy picture showing how it is wired including power, and grounds. Include links to technical information to each of the hardware items. Reason for the links is many, it helps us to understand the part you have, there are many items with the same name but are not electrically the same. Second it saves a lot of time looking and guessing is that the correct one. We want to help but we need yours to accomplish that. Thanks st2000!

Comment: I will share rest of the details soon

Answer (score 3):

There will always be noise in the output an [Analog to Digital Converter (ADC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter).

> An ADC converts a continuous-time and continuous-amplitude analog
> signal to a discrete-time and discrete-amplitude digital signal. The
> conversion involves quantization of the input, so it necessarily
> introduces a small amount of error or noise.

All one can do is mitigate the noise.  Consider cleaning up your power supply.  Make sure your voltage reference is well filtered.  Inspect these power rails with an oscilloscope if one is available.  Also consider keeping all wiring as short as possible and avoid using [Bread Boards](https://www.adafruit.com/product/239) as they tend to introduce noise in sensitive circuits.

When using [exponential averaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) consider the equation / code can be modified easily to accommodate very noisy signals at the sacrifice of responsiveness.  If the application can tolerate the delay, the decay of historical samples can be lowered such that what most consider noise can be filtered out.  One can do this by picking very small values for alpha in the following equation found on wikipedia.org:

[image]